# MarkLogic Server Crashing - I Think Too Many Records Are Being Returned

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I've written an XQuery that doesn't return using the CQ web application.

I thought the below would work, but the server still hangs.

```
declare namespace data = "http://marklogic.com/ps/data";
/data:doc/data:provider[ 1 to 5 ]
```

Any ideas? It doesn't hang if I search down the tree. I am trying to explore the data structures at this point so I need at least one provider returned.

Thanks-in-advance,

Guido

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need parenthesis around your XPath steps. I think you have asked the server to load up all of the **/data:doc/data:provider** elements. Sort them in document order and then, grab the first 5. But if you have millions or billions of those elements, it will have to get them all. Which is probably taking a long time. Try this instead:

```
declare namespace data = "http://marklogic.com/ps/data";
(/data:doc/data:provider)[ 1 to 5 ]
```

-Danny

Comment: Right solution, wrong reason. The original expression is returning the first 5 data:provider children of every data:doc document element. Danny's answer returns the first 5 elements that match the whole path.

Comment: Yet I think the solution is incomplete, because it should be `[position() = 1 to 5]`, or better `[position() le 5]`, because the XQuery 1.0 rules for predicate truth value and effective boolean value do not allow using a sequence of position values by itself. In fact an error should be raised. Or does Marklogic do something different here?

Comment: In MarkLogic xquery version "1.0-ml", it allows the [1 to 5] positional syntax, which was allowed in earlier versions of XQuery.  "1.0" is the strict dialect, and it would require the position() function.  And thanks John, I should have got that right....